# Unfortunately, [Your app] has stopped. No logs show in logcat

Tags: android, android-studio

I encountered this error when implementing an android app, my code here(in `adapter` file):

```
public View getView(...){
...
if (guild == null || guild.getMembers() == null) {
            // we have not get this guild details
            LoadGuildDetailsTask loadGuildDetailsTask = new LoadGuildDetailsTask(guild.getGuildID());
            Utils.executeAsyncTask(loadGuildDetailsTask);
        }
}
```

This is `LoadGuildDetailsTask` asyntask:

```
//load guild detail
    public class LoadGuildDetailsTask extends AsynTaskBase<Void, Void, Guild> {
        private String guildId;
        public LoadGuildDetailsTask (String guildId){
            this.guildId = guildId;
        }

        @Override
        protected Guild doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (guildId != null) {
                MMClientContext clientContext = new MMClientContext(context);
                SessionManager sessionManager = ((MoomeeApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getSessionManager();

                try {
                    Log.d("LoadGuildDetailsTask", "guildId before request details: " + guildId);
                    Guild returnedGuild = clientContext.getGuildDetails(new
                            GetGuildDetailsRequestData(guildId), sessionManager.getSessionCookie());
                    if (returnedGuild != null)
                        return returnedGuild;
                }
                catch (MMConnector.NetWorkErrorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                respCode = MMCommand.INTERNET_CONNECTION_ERROR;
            }
            respCode = MMCommand.INTERNET_CONNECTION_ERROR;
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Guild returnedGuild) {
            super.onPostExecute(returnedGuild);
            Log.v(getClass().getName(), "success return guild: "+returnedGuild);
            setUpLayoutAfterGetGuildDetails(returnedGuild);

        }

        @Override
        public void setActivity(DialogableActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }
    }
```

This is the function to show flag:

```
//set up layout visible
    private void setUpLayoutAfterGetGuildDetails (Guild returnedGuild) {
        FeedHolder holder = null;
        if (returnedGuild != null) {
            if (!isMember(returnedGuild)) {
                holder.feedFlagImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function to check if the user is member of guild or not:

```
//check is member or not
    private boolean isMember(Guild guild) {
        if (guild != null && guild.isMember()) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

The flow of these code is: When `guild` values satisfy the condition(in getView), we implement `LoadGuildDetailsTask` which will call `setUpLayoutAfterGetGuildDetails()` function while this function call `isMember()` function. So after all code done correctly, we will know that the `feedFlagImage` can be set to `VISIBLE` or not. Unfortunately, after building this code, I run my app and got this error. I checked the log in logcat but nothing show there, I also searched this kind of error but there is no solution which can solve my problem. Can someone tell me which steps I have done incorrectly or where my code went wrong?

Comment: initialize the holder in setUpLayoutAfterGetGuildDetails method

Comment: its really possible for an app to crash without any log?

Comment: @RaviGadipudi I already initialized the `holder` to null, that's wrong?

Comment: @Nanoc I'm not sure, but in my case of error, nothing shows

Comment: initialize with constructor not null.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added this code long time before, so I suppose that my problem not cause by this one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Logcat that is not visible:

Keep in mind that the logcat might disconnect from your app after you click OK in the crash window.

Did the log messages from before the crash appear in your console? If they also aren't there, try restarting Android Studio/your emulator

Comment: There was no log msg before the crash appear, restarting got the same as before

Comment: Did you restart both Android Studio and the emulator?

Comment: Maybe you have a filter set? Are looking for the log messages of the correct package?

Comment: this is the strange log after I set `no filter`: `8547-15994/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV﹕ Widevine DRM not supported on this device
    android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.`

Comment: With no filter, all log messages from the system and all other running apps/services are shown. You should filter for your apps package name. The error you got could be coming from any other process running so is most likely not related to your issue